# Next Auth login into Keycloak Account in Cypress Test

Tags: next.js, cypress, keycloak, next-auth

I'm trying to write some e2e tests with Cypress for my NextJs Application. I'm using Next Auth to log in to my keycloak account using OAuth. I display certain nav bar elements only to users with certain keycloak roles which is why I've created a test realm with test users for the e2e tests. My problem is that after the test tries to log in I get a `State cookie was missing.` error from the next auth and I can't figure out why that is happening. It works if I try the test steps by myself.

Test when I do it in my browser:

- open the home page
- click on the login
- get redirected to keycloak
- enter username
- enter password
- click on the login
- get redirected to the home page
- login successful

Test when cypress does it:

- open the home page
- click on the login
- get redirected to keycloak
- enter username
- enter password
- click on the login
- get redirected to the next auth error page
- log message with `State cookie was missing.`
- login failed

What could cause that behavior of cypress?

help is much appreciated :S

EDIT:

I figured out that the `next-auth.state` cookie still exists when re-entering my page (tested with `cy.getCookies().then(currentSubject => console.log("Cookies:", currentSubject));`) after login button click which confuses me even more since next auth tells me that it does **not** exist :S

EDIT 2:

It seems like cypress has that cookie but it doesn't get to my web app since the request which reaches by the application doesn't contain any cookie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed by rewriting next-auth's cookies so that they were `SameSite=None`. Here's the code I used (going via Auth0 in my case):

```typescript
function loginViaAuth0Ui(username: string, password: string) {
  cy.intercept("/api/auth/**", (req) =>
      req.on("response", (res) => {
        const setCookies = res.headers["set-cookie"]
        res.headers["set-cookie"] = (
            Array.isArray(setCookies) ? setCookies : [setCookies]
        )
            .filter((x) => x?.startsWith('next-auth'))
            .map((headerContent) => {
                  const replaced = headerContent.replace(
                      /samesite=(lax|strict)/gi,
                      "secure; samesite=none"
                  )
                  // console.log('replaced', headerContent, 'with', replaced)
                  return replaced
                }
            )
      })
  )

  cy.visit('account')
  cy.findByTestId('auth0-button').click()

  cy.origin('https://my-site.uk.auth0.com/', {args: {username, password}}, ({username, password}) => {
    cy.get('input#username').type(username)
    cy.get('input#password').type(password, {log: false})
    cy.contains('button[value=default]', 'Continue').click()
  })


  cy.url().should('include', '/account')
}
```

### TL;DR

The problem is related to cookies, and is described in detail here: https://www.tomoliver.net/posts/cypress-samesite-problem (and from where I based my code) — In summary: next-auth's cookies are `SameSite=Lax`, and because Cypress runs inside an iframe-like context the redirects are not "top-level", so Chromium blocks the request. You can see this in the blocked cookies in Chromium's request under the cookies tab, giving the reason:

[image: Blocked cookies inside Chromium]

The sample code intercepts just the responses from next-auth (intercepting more would be slower) and rewrites the cookies to be `SameSite=None`, so they are not blocked by Chromium.